# XMLSlartlet Grep xml node and replace

Tags: xmlstarlet

how to find blocks of node and replace by custom block using xmlstarlet

Below my xml sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
    <input>
    <par_denominator nil="true"/>
    <par_follow_source>true</par_follow_source>
    <par_numerator nil="true"/>
    <deblock_enable>Auto</deblock_enable>
    <deblock_strength>0</deblock_strength>
    <no_psi>false</no_psi>
    </input>
 <h264_settings>
    <par_denominator nil="true"/>
    <par_follow_source>true</par_follow_source>
    <par_numerator nil="true"/>
 </h264_settings>
</job>
```

I'd like to replace all the block contains

```
    <par_denominator nil="true"/>
    <par_follow_source>true</par_follow_source>
    <par_numerator nil="true"/>
```

replacement value

```
    <par_denominator>1</par_denominator>
    <par_follow_source>false</par_follow_source>
    <par_numerator>1</par_numerator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`xmlstarlet`** solution:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//*["par_denominator" or "par_numerator"][@nil="true"]' -v 1 \
-u '//par_follow_source[.="true"]' -v 'false' \
-d '//*["par_denominator" or "par_numerator"]/@nil' input.xml
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
  <input>
    <par_denominator>1</par_denominator>
    <par_follow_source>false</par_follow_source>
    <par_numerator>1</par_numerator>
    <deblock_enable>Auto</deblock_enable>
    <deblock_strength>0</deblock_strength>
    <no_psi>false</no_psi>
  </input>
  <h264_settings>
    <par_denominator>1</par_denominator>
    <par_follow_source>false</par_follow_source>
    <par_numerator>1</par_numerator>
  </h264_settings>
</job>
```

Comment: Thanks Roman it works but some of the nodes with nil="true" the value changed to 1. I want to implement in par_denominator and par_numerator only. Here is my full xml pastebin.com/nM5zUYRT

Comment: I think instead of `["par_denominator" or "par_numerator"]` you'd want something like `[self::par_denominator or self::par_numerator]` or `[local-name()="par_denominator" or local-name()="par_numerator"]`

Comment: @jojo, but the file you shared doesn't contain `nil="true"` at all

Comment: Hi roman my apology not to shared full xml. [self::par_denominator or self::par_numerator]  works fine now.  I'd to know how can i achieve in vice versa for par_numerator and par_denominator? from  par_denominator>1</par_denominator>
 to <par_denominator nil="true"/> .